# jQuery and .Net CRUD searching

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net

I've got the problem with my jQuery function to search the elements from the list that are matching the entered string. It's always showing that no data was found.

I've tried with various modifications, but nothing helped.

Here is the code for jQuery function

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#SearchBtn").click(function () {
        console.log("ttt");
        var SearchBy = $("#SearchBy").val();
        var SearchValue = $("#Search").val();
        var SetData = $("#SetStudentList");
        SetData.html("");
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/Home/GetSearchingData?SearchBy=" + SearchBy + "&SearchValue=" + SearchValue,
            contentType: "html",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.length == 0) {
                    SetData.append('<tr style="color:red"><td colspan="3">No Match Data</td></tr>')
                }
                else {
                    $.each(result, function (index, value) {
                        var Data = "<tr class='row_" + StudentList[i].StudentId + "'>" +
                            "<td>" + StudentList[i].StudentId + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + StudentList[i].StudentName + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + StudentList[i].Email + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + StudentList[i].DepartmentName + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + "<a href='#' class='btn btn-warning' onclick='EditStudentRecord(" + StudentList[i].StudentId + ")'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></a>" + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='DeleteStudentRecord(" + StudentList[i].StudentId + ")'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>" + "</td>" +
                            "</tr>";
                        SetData.append(Data);

                    });
                }
            }

        });
    });

});
```

Html for search button:

```
          <b>Search By : </b>
    <select id="SearchBy">
        <option value="StudentID">Student ID</option>
        <option value="StudentName">Student Name</option>
        <option value="Email">Email</option>
        <option value="Department">Department</option>
    </select> <br /><br />
    @Html.TextBox("Search")<input type="submit" id="SearchBtn" value="Search" /> <br /><br />
```

Methods from controller (searching and also getlist and getbyID, as i was even trying to call getlist after search button is clicked, but always there was info 'no matching results'):

```
    public JsonResult GetSearchingData (string SearchBy, string SearchValue)
    {
        List<StudentViewModel> StuList = new List<StudentViewModel>();
        if (SearchBy == "Student ID")
        {
            try
            {
                int Id = Convert.ToInt32(SearchValue);
                StuList = db.tblStudent.Where(x => x.StudentId == Id || SearchValue == null).Select(x => new StudentViewModel
                {
                    StudentId = x.StudentId,
                    StudentName = x.StudentName,
                    Email = x.Email,
                    DepartmentName = x.tblDepartment.DepartmentName
                }).ToList();

            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Is Not A ID ", SearchValue);
            }
            return Json(StuList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            StuList = db.tblStudent.Where(x=>x.StudentName.Contains(SearchValue) || SearchValue == null).Select(x => new StudentViewModel
            {
                StudentId = x.StudentId,
                StudentName = x.StudentName,
                Email = x.Email,
                DepartmentName = x.tblDepartment.DepartmentName
            }).ToList();
            return Json(StuList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

         public JsonResult GetStudentList()
    {
        List<StudentViewModel> StuList = db.tblStudent.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).Select(x => new StudentViewModel
        {
            StudentId = x.StudentId,
            StudentName = x.StudentName,
            Email = x.Email,
            DepartmentName = x.tblDepartment.DepartmentName
        }).ToList();

        return Json(StuList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult GetStudentById (int StudentId)
    {
        tblStudent model = db.tblStudent.Where(x => x.StudentId == StudentId).SingleOrDefault();
        string value = string.Empty;
        value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        });
        return Json(value, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `SearchBy=="Student ID"` should be `SearchBy=="StudentID"`. Also try adding [FromQueryString] before both your parameters `GetSearchingData([FromQueryString] SearchBy, [FromQueryString] SearchValue)`

Comment: Just put the condition db.tblStudent.Where(x => x.StudentId == Id). only for Student ID